# Incoming Network Connection alert does not dismiss

Tags: network, firewall, alert

I develop web applications and often get the Firewall alert on a new version of my code:

[image: Firewall alert]

This is OK (although I would prefer to just answer one and be done with it).  The problem is that selecting either Deny or Allow does not make the alert window go away; it just hangs around on the screen even after multiple selections.  Eventually it dismisses, but it may be many minutes before it does. I'm running Monterey 12.4.